# Pandas, groupby where column value is greater than x

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like this

```
    timestamp   avg_hr  hr_quality  avg_rr  rr_quality  activity    sleep_summary_id

    1422404668  66      229             0       0           13              78
    1422404670  64      223             0       0           20              78
    1422404672  64      216             0       0           11              78
    1422404674  66      198             0       40          9               78
    1422404676  65      184             0       30          3               78
    1422404678  64      173             0       10          17              78
    1422404680  66      199             0       20          118             78
```

I'm trying to group the data by `timestamp`,`sleep id` and `rr_quality`, where `rr_quality` is `> 0`

I've tried the following and none of them seems to work

```
 df3 = df2.groupby([df2.index.hour,'sleep_summary_id',df2['rr_quality']>0])

 df3 = df2.groupby([df2.index.hour,'sleep_summary_id','rr_quality'>0])

 df3 = df2.groupby([df2.index.hour,'sleep_summary_id',['rr_quality']>0])
```

All of them returns a keyerror.

**EDIT:**

Also can't seem to be able to pass more than one filter at a time.
I tried the following:

```
df2[df2['rr_quality'] >= 150, df2['hr_quality'] > 200]
df2[df2['rr_quality'] >= 150, ['hr_quality'] > 200]
df2[[df2['rr_quality'] >= 150, ['hr_quality'] > 200]]
```

returns: `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the simplest thing to do here is to filter the df first and then perform the groupby:

```
df2[df2['rr_quality'] > 0].groupby([df2.index.hour,'sleep_summary_id'])
```

**EDIT**

If you're intending to assign this back to your original df:

```
df2.loc[df2['rr_quality'] > 0, 'AVG_HR'] = df2[df2['rr_quality'] >= 150].groupby([df2.index.hour,'emfit_sleep_summary_id'])['avg_hr'].transform('mea‌​n')
```

The `loc` call will mask the lhs so that the result of the transform aligns correctly

To filter using multiple conditions you need to use the array comparision operators `&`, `|` and `~` for `and`, `or` and `not` respectively, additionally you need to wrap the conditions in parentheses due to operator precedence:

```
df2[(df2['rr_quality'] >= 150) & (df2['hr_quality'] > 200)]
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but I wanted to add that there is [an official function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) to do exactly this. Transforming the example from pandas to your case:

```
grouped_df2= df2.groupby([df2.index.hour,'sleep_summary_id','rr_quality'])
grouped_df2.filter(lambda x: x['rr_quality'] > 0.)
```